# Python calculate total value and percentage of it in dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am definitely doing it wrong at this point and my brain is melting.
I have this data

```
queryset = [
{'source_id': '1', 'gender_id': 'female', 'total': 12928604, 'percentage': {'neutral': [8284384, 64.08], 'positive': [3146438, 24.34], 'negative': [1497782, 11.59]}},
{'source_id': '1', 'gender_id': 'male', 'total': 15238856, 'percentage': {'neutral': [10042152, 65.9], 'positive': [2476421, 16.25], 'negative': [2720283, 17.85]}},
{'source_id': '1', 'gender_id': 'null', 'total': 6, 'percentage': {'neutral': [5, 83.33], 'positive': [1, 16.67], 'negative': [0, 0.0]}},
{'source_id': '2', 'gender_id': 'female', 'total': 23546499, 'percentage': {'neutral': [15140308, 64.3], 'positive': [5372964, 22.82], 'negative': [3033227, 12.88]}},
{'source_id': '2', 'gender_id': 'male', 'total': 15349754, 'percentage': {'neutral': [10137025, 66.04], 'positive': [2413350, 15.72], 'negative': [2799379, 18.24]}},
{'source_id': '2', 'gender_id': 'null', 'total': 3422, 'percentage': {'neutral': [2464, 72.0], 'positive': [437, 12.77], 'negative': [521, 15.23]}}
{'source_id': '3', 'gender_id': 'female', 'total': 29417761, 'percentage': {'neutral': [18944384, 64.4], 'positive': [7181996, 24.41], 'negative': [3291381, 11.19]}},
{'source_id': '3', 'gender_id': 'male', 'total': 27200788, 'percentage': {'neutral': [17827887, 65.54], 'positive': [4179990, 15.37], 'negative': [5192911, 19.09]}},
{'source_id': '3', 'gender_id': 'null', 'total': 32909, 'percentage': {'neutral': [22682, 68.92], 'positive': [4005, 12.17], 'negative': [6222, 18.91]}}
]
```

my desired output is

```
    [ {'source_id:1', 'total': 28167466(sum of 'male, female, null' total
   values for source id=1) , percentage: {'neutral':[18326541, 
   65.06(getting   the % out of neutral value from total)], 'positive': 
   [5622859, 19.96], 'negative':[4218065,14.97], {and do the same for all sources}]
```

what I do but doesn't work, I have 3if statement is for all the 3 IDs

```
for i in queryset:
if i['source_id'] == '1':
    output['percentage'] = {
        'neutral': [sum(i['percentage']['neutral'][0] for i in queryset if i['source_id'] == '1'),
                    round(output['negative'] / output['2_total'] * 100, 2)],

        'positive': [sum(i['percentage']['positive'][0] for i in queryset if i['source_id'] == '2'),
                     round(output['positive'] / output['2_total'] * 100, 2)],

        'negative': [sum(i['percentage']['negative'][0] for i in queryset if i['source_id'] == '2'),
                     round(output['negative'] / output['2_total'] * 100, 2)]}
```

Comment: can you post your data in its original format, is it a list of dictionaries?

Comment: it's a list of dictiionaries yes, i iteerate through it and get the data i showed above :)

Comment: can you please edit and post it as is, it's not usable in its current state

Comment: @aws_apprentice updated

Comment: You should try to edit the desired output at least. I'm not understanding what you need :(

Comment: @learn2day I have updated it as much as i could, i hope its clear enough :)
But from what I can see ```aws_apprentice``` is on the correct understanding what is needed  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright if I understand correctly this is what you want:

```
unique_ids = set([item.get('source_id') for item in queryset]) # unique source ids

output = []

for id_ in unique_ids:
    # only grab items that match the current source id
    to_agg = list(filter(lambda x: x.get('source_id') == id_, queryset))

    # sum the total field for this source id
    total = sum((item.get('total') for item in to_agg))

    # aggregate the data for neutral/positive/negative
    percents = [item.get('percentage') for item in to_agg]
    negatives = sum((item.get('negative')[0] for item in percents))
    positives = sum((item.get('positive')[0] for item in percents))
    neutrals = sum((item.get('neutral')[0] for item in percents))

    # construct the final dictionary
    d = {'source_id': id_,
         'total': total,
         'percentage': {'neutral': [neutrals, round(neutrals / total * 100, 2)],
                        'positives': [positives, round(positives / total * 100, 2)],
                        'negative': [negatives, round(negatives / total * 100, 2)]}}

    output.append(d)

sorted(output, key=lambda x: x.get('source_id'))

[{'percentage': {'negative': [4218065, 14.97],
   'neutral': [18326541, 65.06],
   'positives': [5622860, 19.96]},
  'source_id': '1',
  'total': 28167466},
 {'percentage': {'negative': [5833127, 15.0],
   'neutral': [25279797, 64.99],
   'positives': [7786751, 20.02]},
  'source_id': '2',
  'total': 38899675},
 {'percentage': {'negative': [8490514, 14.99],
   'neutral': [36794953, 64.95],
   'positives': [11365991, 20.06]},
  'source_id': '3',
  'total': 56651458}]
```

Edit: Just keep in mind I have not optimized this answer so it might not be as fast as you need it to be if your query set is large.

Comment: Thank you, I have it on another laptop gonna check a bit later.  Speed at this very point doesnt matter, gonna refactor it later on anyways. Thank you a lot for the effort !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` to add up the totals:

```
from collections import Counter

counters = {}
for row in queryset:
    # gender_id not needed
    del row['gender_id']
    # Pull the subtotals from 'percentage'
    # into the parent dictionary, keeping only
    # the subtotals in first list item,
    # not the percentages
    percentages = row.pop('percentage')
    for k, v in percentages.items():
        percentages[k] = v[0]
    row.update(percentages)
    # Use 'source_id' as key for the 
    # counters dictionary
    index = row.pop('source_id')
    if index not in counters:
        counters[index] = Counter(row)
    else:
        counters[index].update(row)
```

This gives you the following:

```
{'1': Counter({'total': 28167466,
          'neutral': 18326541,
          'positive': 5622860,
          'negative': 4218065}),
 '2': Counter({'total': 38899675,
          'neutral': 25279797,
          'positive': 7786751,
          'negative': 5833127}),
 '3': Counter({'total': 56651458,
          'neutral': 36794953,
          'positive': 11365991,
          'negative': 8490514})}
```

From this, you can easily count the percentages and move it into the format required.